# How to create a process permanent file from an application program

Tags: openvms

How can I create process permanent file (like DCL does) from an application executable (I happen to be coding in Fortran, but I suspect that's not important to the answer).

I would like to create/open the file in one EXE, then be able to access it from DCL or another EXE in the same procedure.

I have a general understanding of RMS internals, so answers with FAB or RAB structures will probably be understood. As a guess, SUPERVISOR mode is involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asked and answered. :-).

```
Note 870.1    How do you open process permanent files and channels        1 of 5
QUARK::LIONEL "Ad Astra"                              5 lines   1-JAN-1989 00:15
                          < PPFs only through CLIs >
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

For question 1, the ONLY way to create a PPF is through a CLI such
as DCL.  The usual method is the DCL OPEN command.  From languages,
you can only open existing PPFs.
```

Nothing has changed since.

PPF are very restrictive ( minimal buffers, no global buffers, ...) and should be created BEFORE with DCL before a program tries to use it.

What problem are you really trying to solve?

Hein

Comment: fwiw, you can probably use CMEXEC, descend  to SUPER and flip the FAB$V_PPF bit in FAB$L_FOP

Comment: I don't have a need at the moment (Thanks for re-posting the previous answer). I remember where this would have been handy in the past and wanted to add it to my bag of tricks. I'll experiment with the CMEXEC, etc. and report back if I get that to work.

Comment: Ah, the memories of VAX NOTES at DEC.